# Qml Text new line

Tags: string, qt, text, newline, qml

If I enter: "Subject:" + "/n" + vak + "/n" + klas as the text property of a Text element it returns everything in a straight line with "/n"'s in.

How can I get it to create new lines?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know qt or qml, but in most languages the [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) is a backslash, not a regular slash, so the escape sequence would be `\n` for a newline

Answer (score 1):

Enter the text as "Hello \n World"
it works